# Why does my UIApplicationDelegate receive applicationDidBecomeActive when pulling down notification center?

Tags: ios

I've built a bare application with no functionality in XCode, and put logging statements in the applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationWillResignActive methods.

When I swipe down to show the notification center, I see the following:

2018-01-03 10:18:16.867028+0000 BareProject[1165:2053601] Resigning active

2018-01-03 10:18:17.510713+0000 BareProject[1165:2053601] Active

2018-01-03 10:18:17.634805+0000 BareProject[1165:2053601] Resigning active

Is this intended? My code does quite a lot of work when becoming active, only to have the rug pulled out from it again about 120ms later, and it seems that the documentation says I should be using applicationDidBecomeActive to restart tasks:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive?language=objc

I tried this on ios 10.3 and this behavior does not exist.

Comment: This behavior still exists in iOS 12. This is a horror.

Comment: Interestingly enough this issue also exists when the iPhone locks itself. First `applicationDidBecomeActive` then immediately `applicationWillResignActive`

Comment: to my above comment: This happens when the notification center already completely covered the screen. THIS IS A HUGE BUG IMO.

Comment: iOS15 still has this issue

Answer (score 11):

There are actually two issues, the unexpected call to `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and the duplicated call to `applicationWillResignActive:`.

"Pull down" to show a notification center used to work properly on iOS 9. Only `applicationWillResignActive:` used to be called by the system, just verified it with iOS 9 Simulator.

On iOS 11.2.6, the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` gets called as you described which seems like an Apple bug. In this particular case, the system behavior conflicts with the documentation. Here is another example where the documentation deviates from the behavior you observed https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW10

> When your app is moved back to the active state, its
>   applicationDidBecomeActive: method should reverse any of the steps
>   taken in the applicationWillResignActive: method.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is a bug, that made it to regular behavior

you need to look for `applicationDidEnterBackground`

however, in case you need to handle your code for this
you can use the following to NOT run code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` when the notification center swipes down

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var didEnterBackground = true
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
       if !didEnterBackground {
           return
       }
       didEnterBackground = false

       // run your code       
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        didEnterBackground = true
    }
    
}
```